# Same url mapping for controllers and repositories using Spring Data Rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I'm using Spring Data Rest for automatic rest endpoints and HATEOAS. When I go to localhost:8080 I get:

```
   {
  "_links": {
    "books": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/books{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "users": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/users"
    },
    "customers": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/customers"
    },
    "profile": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/profile"
    }
  }
}
```

GET @ localhost:8080/books gives me:
`There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'GET' not supported`

Here is my repo:

```
    public interface BookRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Book, Long> {
  Optional<Book> findByIsbn(String isbn);
}
```

My controller:

```
   @RestController
public class BookController {
  private final BookService bookService;

  @Autowired
  public BookController(BookService bookService) {
    this.bookService = bookService;
  }

  @PostMapping("/books")
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
  public Book newToDo(@RequestBody BookDTO bookDTO) {
    return bookService.addNewBook(bookDTO);
  }

  @PutMapping("/books/{id}")
  public ResponseEntity<?> editToDo(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody double newPrice) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(bookService.changePrice(id, newPrice), HttpStatus.OK);
  }
}
```

Without that controller `GET @ localhost:8080/books` works perfectly fine - repository itself sets out this endpoint and I can search through all my books. When I add those POST and PUT methods I'm getting an error.
Is there a way to use repository for `GET requests @ localhost:8080/books` and normal controller methods for `POST @ localhost:8080/books` ?

Answer (score 0):

For implementation of custom endpoints try to use `@RepositoryRestController` instead if `@RestController` as `Spring Data REST` uses a different flow from `Spring Web` and `@RestController` annotations may simply not work and conflict `Spring Data REST`.

You can also add `@ExposesResourceFor` annotation for supporting HATEOAS links.